# Removing Subview after the completion of Animation - Transition

Tags: objective-c, ios8, catransition

On a button click, I have placed a TRANSPARENT View on the current View. For the transparent view to cover the entire screen including navigation bar, I have coded like this :

```
[AppDelegate.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:coverView];
```

In the button click action,I have put some animation code.

Now, on a button click in Transparent View, I have put the following code to perform a sliding transition effect:

```
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDuration:0.8];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [[TransparentView.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
    [TransparentView removefromSuperview];
```

I need the transparent view to slide towards left/right (in other words..removing TransparentView from view) and MainView should appear as before.

But its not working..
Could anyone help on this ?

Comment: Instead of [TransparentView.view layer] use [self.view layer] and then check.

Comment: i checked it already.but the main view gets the animation effect. What I need is to slide transparent view & make the main view visible.
When I put [self.view layer]....., the main view itself slides and main view gets displayed

Answer (score 1):

arturdev is partially correct!! What he is doing now is -
-->  Adding a CATransition animation from left to right for 0.8 seconds after which the view is still there.
--> then removing it from superview.

Instead of that, hide the transparentView by changing its frame (here I am displacing its x co-ordinate by frame width). And then add transition.

```
[coverView setFrame:CGRectMake([coverView frame].size.width, 0, coverView.frame.size.width, coverView.frame.size.height)];
[CATransaction begin];
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    [coverView removeFromSuperview];
}];
[animation setDuration:0.8];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[[coverView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
[CATransaction commit];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[CATransaction begin];
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    [TransparentView removefromSuperview];
}];
[animation setDuration:0.8];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[[TransparentView.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Transparent View gets slided twice.Then I added

 ---------------> animation.repeatCount=1;                        
It is also not working